# Trouble decoding the sniffed output

Tags: python, byte, decode, packet-sniffers, network-monitoring

Trying to develop a packet sniffer with python so i can capture data of a specific program running on windows and organize it in a user-friendly manner.

so far I've got only the following code

```
import scapy.all as scapy

def sniff(interface):
    scapy.sniff(iface=interface, store=False, prn=process_sniff_packet)

def process_sniff_packet(packet):
    print(packet)

sniff("Wi-Fi")
```

Not my own code but this might be what i need to tap into the pc's network. I'm open to suggestions on this as well.

But the output from this is total gibberish.

```
b'\x8cUJ\xd5[\x1f\xfcJ\xe9\xc8\xbe\xc3\x08\x00E\x00\x00\xe0\x00\x00@\x00:\x11(\xd2\xac\xd9\xa9\xae\xc0\xa8\x00\x0b\x01\xbb\xc7\x92\x00\xcc\xb8\xf0Q\x13\x08\x15\xcf\x88\xdb\xc9?\xd83\xfe}n
\xee\x8a\xd3M}\xfa\xa8Qw\xee\x1d&;\xfdh\xdb\n\xfcP;\xd2\xac4.\x81\x93\x1b6K(sz\xff\xacU\xa5o\x81\x07\x8a\xfd4\xb5abd\xad\xa4\x0e\xbe\x92\x08\xda\x06\x14\x89\xbc\x92\xddM\x99\x80A\xb1?\x8b
\x7fm<\xe4\x1d\x97\xde\xff\x89\xe0\xc0\xb9#\x17\xf7\x05\xc2\x1e6\xf5 vu\xdbT\xfeM@\xde\xa8\x8c\x06>$\xab\x04L\xc6c^uG\x1aE\xf0\xbb\xeau1\xa5/q\xca\xc9\xb0\xc2\xb0\xb3\xec\x9a\x9f\xeb\xb8\
x0b\xad\xffP\xb9#\x125\x177Q\x0b<~_f\xde\x93\xc1xV\xc8.\xfd8\xef\xb999c\xe6%\x14\x13\x02\x88\xd2w\xef\x18\xaa\xe1\xcf\x16\xd3]\x01 ;$\xa6c\xa2'
b'\xfcJ\xe9\xc8\xbe\xc3\x8cUJ\xd5[\x1f\x08\x00E\x00\x00?\xed\x84@\x00@\x11\x00\x00\xc0\xa8\x00\x0b\xac\xd9\xa9\xae\xc7\x92\x01\xbb\x00+\x17xI\xa8D\x9f\xdd\x8d1\x1a\xd6\xbe\xfef\xf40\x93U\
x95)\xf0\xda\x19r\x04F\xb6[\xa0E\xad\xf2}p\t%\xbe'
b'\xfcJ\xe9\xc8\xbe\xc3\x8cUJ\xd5[\x1f\x08\x00E\x00\x00=\xed\x85@\x00@\x11\x00\x00\xc0\xa8\x00\x0b\xac\xd9\xa9\xae\xc7\x92\x01\xbb\x00)\x17vG\xa8D\x9f\xdd\x8d1\x1a\xd6\xe4\x00 \x8f\xf9\x8
7\x80Ri\xee!R\t{\xd9\x81\xa4F\xa3\x98\xe8\xbeO\x8c'
b'\x8cUJ\xd5[\x1f\xfcJ\xe9\xc8\xbe\xc3\x08\x00E\x00\x005\x00\x00@\x00:\x11)}\xac\xd9\xa9\xae\xc0\xa8\x00\x0b\x01\xbb\xc7\x92\x00!\x02\xa8W\x87\x1a`Im\xdcS[\xfb\x89\x94,\xbd\xb4S\xdbK\xf1\
r\xe3\x85\xfbQ\x13'
b'\xfcJ\xe9\xc8\xbe\xc3\x8cUJ\xd5[\x1f\x08\x00E\x00\x00)d#@\x00@\x06\x00\x00\xc0\xa8\x00\x0bl\xb1w\xbc\nV\x14l\xd2\x8d,\xc1N"\x0b^P\x10\x02\x01\xa5<\x00\x00\x00'
b'\x8cUJ\xd5[\x1f\xfcJ\xe9\xc8\xbe\xc3\x08\x00E\x00\x004E\x04\x00\x00)\x06\xa7\x9fl\xb1w\xbc\xc0\xa8\x00\x0b\x14l\nVN"\x0b^\xd2\x8d,\xc2\x80\x10\x01\t]b\x00\x00\x01\x01\x05\n\xd2\x8d,\xc1
\xd2\x8d,\xc2'
```

I 've tried the `print(str(packet, 'utf-8'))` but it gives an error saying "decoding to str: need a bytes-like object, Ether found", which baffles me because I thought this was bytes, hence the bytes to strings code.

.decode attribute doesn't work either.

I don't know what the output I'm getting is and I don't know if I'm getting the right output in the first place.

Looking for kind answers.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print the whole packet, which includes TCP/IP headers which are binary. Instead, you should try to only print the inner payload. Here your modified process_sniff_packet to print the TCP payload

```
def process_sniff_packet(packet):
    if scapy.TCP in packet:
        payload = bytes(packet[scapy.TCP].payload)

        try:
            print(payload.decode("utf-8"))
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            pass
```

You can test this by visiting an HTTP-only website (e.g. httpforever.com). Please note that most of the network traffic uses TLS, so its payload will be encrypted